# Return rows where field contains only alpha(no numbers) characters

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm going to oversimplify. This is for Oracle SQL. I have a table with `USER_ID` column.

User_id varies in length and is `VARCHAR`. Some user IDs have letters AND numbers in them. Some have ONLY letters.

USER_NAME Examples: DAVIDMR and JOHNS5423

I need to have 2 separate queries: One that returns USER_ID where it does NOT have any numbers and one where USER_ID must have a number in it.

I've tried various permutations of `WHERE USER_ID NOT LIKE '%[0-9]%'`, but it either returns no records or returns all records.

Comment: I think you need to be using `REGEXP_LIKE` here...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `REGEXP_LIKE`.

For the ones not having digits in user_id:

```
select *
from t
where not regexp_like(USER_ID, '[[:digit:]]');
```

For having digits in user_id:

```
select *
from t
where regexp_like(USER_ID, '[[:digit:]]');
```

Another way is using `TRANSLATE`:

For the ones not having digits in user_id:

```
select *
from t
where length(user_id) = length(translate(user_id,' 1234567890',' '));
```

For the ones having digits in user_id:

```
select *
from t
where length(user_id) <> length(translate(user_id,' 1234567890',' '));
```